# Pandas assignment unexpected behavior

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

I am just playing with pandas, trying to modify values of a column.

My initial dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], y=[10, 11, 15, 14, 14, 25, 25)
    )
df.index = list('abcdefg')
```

with output:

```
>>> df
       x   y
    a  1  10
    b  2  11
    c  3  15
    d  4  14
    e  5  14
    f  6  25
    g  7  25
```

Suppose that I want to modify the first element of `x` column. I do:

`df.loc['a', 'x'] = 100`

which outputs:

```
>>> df.loc['a', 'x'] = 100
>>> df
     x   y
a  100  10
b    2  11
c    3  15
d    4  14
e    5  14
f    6  25
g    7  25
```

What I can't understand is why the following:

```
>>> j = df['x']
>>> j['a'] = 200
>>> df
     x   y
a  200  10
b    2  11
c    3  15
d    4  14
e    5  14
f    6  25
g    7  25
```

also modifies the first element of `x` column in `df`. Furthermore:

```
>>> df.loc['a', 'x'] is j['a']
False
```

which means that they don't point to the same object. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You are not performing the correct test. You should rather test:

```
j is df['x']
```

output: `True`

`j` and `df['x']` point to the same Series.

The `False` is explained by the underlying numpy array that does not contain python objects. The object are generated during slicing:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a[0] is a[0]
```

output: `False`

Comment: Is this object generation during slicing a characteristic of Python or just numpy? If `a` is list I am getting output: `True`.

Comment: Of `numpy`, python lists contain "references" to the objects (that's why if you have lists of lists, you can mutate them externally, e.g. `a = [1] ; b = [0, a] ; b[1][0] = 9 ; print(a)`).

Comment: I checked also `df['x'] is df.loc[:, 'x']` which outputs: `True`. But when I am selecting based on index, that is `df['x']['a'] is df.loc[:, 'x']['a']` outputs: `False` which should be attributed to the numpy behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That is why we need `copy` here

```
j = df['x'].copy()
```

Notice after add copy the id number is different

```
id(df['x'])
Out[612]: 140536670316496
id(df['x'].copy())
Out[613]: 140536673228496
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `j = df['x']` only assigns the object reference of `df['x']` to `j`. Anything modified through `j` will impact the same object in memory as the one behind `df['x']`.

If you want to make a copy of the object value behind `df['x']`, store it into `j`, and modify it independently from `df`, you need to use `.copy()` method as:

`j = df['x'].copy()`

Read more about it at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Comment: Check `j['a'] is df['x']['a']` which outputs: `False`.

Comment: I meant without `.copy` that I am getting output: `False`.

Comment: You copied the reference of `df['x']`, so the comparison should be `df['x'] is j` to get a `True`. Then why you get then `False` for the cell `a`? That is because the values in each set are of the primitive type `int`, which natively a new copy of the value is created underneath every time you assign or pass a new one. You could check the reference ID's in both cases: `print(id(j))
print(id(df['x']))
print(id(j['a']))
print(id(df['x']['a']))`